# Get Value from ObjectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a filter like so:

```
public class Err : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result;
    }
}
```

`result` is an object of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult`. It contains a `StatusCode` and a `Value`, but when I try to extract them like so: `context.Result.Value`, I get this error:

> Error  CS1061  'IActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'IActionResult' could be found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is simple - property `Result` of `ActionExecutedContext` has `IActionResult` type which doesn't have property `Value`. You can cast it to `BadRequestObjectResult` to get access to `Value` property:

```
public class Err : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result as BadRequestObjectResult;
        // you can access result.Value here
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but my `Value` object has 2 properties - `Message` and `Status`. I still cant access them even though I can access the `Value` object.

Comment: Never mind. I casted `Value` into the type of my object and exposed the `Message` property. Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron, How did you cast the Value into type of object, because I still could not access sub properties within Value ?